# Translating Graphics Context

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

In the following code below, I'm trying to translate, or more a graphics context for which I'm using `CoreText` to draw on. The first four lines of code flip the coordinate system as CoreText uses the origin from the lower left hand corner. After the coordinate system is flipped I need to move the graphics context down the y axis by `textFrameOriginY` amount. However the following code I'm using isn't working. I'm not that familiar with graphics and was wondering if there is something I'm doing wrong?

```
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, textFrameOriginY);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've flipped the coordinate syste, down is negative and up is positive, so your second translate should be -textFrameOriginY?

Assuming that this is in -drawRect: - remember that you can't draw outside of your bounds, that should help you with debugging the issue...

Answer (score 1):

This line should be,

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, viewHeight-textFrameOriginY);
```

to get proper placing.